# Can I configure separate sound volume for each user?

Tags: 12.04, sound

I want to apply distinct sound volume for distinct users in Ubuntu 12.04. But now all users share the same master volume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1778985). It sets volume level to a particular value after every login. It works with PulseAudio only.

1. Copy default pulse config file to your home location:

   `cp /etc/pulse/default.pa ~/.pulse`
2. In your config file locate the following line:

   `load-module module-always-sink`

   Immediately after the above line, add the following line:

   `set-sink-volume 0 {your-volume-level-here}`

   Volume level is a number in a range 0..65535. For example:

   `set-sink-volume 0 32768`